# jQuery Validate - How to remove a class for error on a specific label?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

See problem in action here: (Kudos to anyone who can help!)

**http://jsfiddle.net/74u7g/**

- When the passwords match I add a green checkmark by adding a class checkMark
- To see the problem change the second password so it does not match and is less than 6 chars.
- I only want to remove the class for this specific input (second password field)

The required text remains green (`class` not removed) if the user later changes their entry (after success) causing an error. How do I successfully remove `class` `checkMark` on error?

```
$("#registerForm").validate({       
    rules: {
    createUsername: {
    required: true,
    email: true
},

    createPassword: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
    },

    createPassword2: {
    equalTo: "#createPassword",
    minlength: 6
    }
},

messages: {
    createPassword: {
    required: "This field is required.",
    minlength: "Password must be 6-15 characters long."
    }
},

success: function(label) {
    if ( $(label).parent().is('#confirmPassContainer') ) {
        $(label).addClass('checkMark').html('&#x2713;'); 
        }   
    }

});
```

I've tried the `highlight` and `error` methods with no success. I've searched high and low for an answer on StackOverflow but no luck yet. Hoping for a solution using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `highlight:` inside your `.validate()`...

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).siblings('label').removeClass('checkMark');
}
```

I believe it will fire every time the form tests invalid... kinda works the opposite of `success:`.

Inside your demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/74u7g/5/

**EDIT:**

`element` refers to the specific `input` element that is being validated.

`errorClass` refers to the `class` that the plugin is using to flag errors.  Not used within this example.

So `$(element)` selects the element with the error, then `.siblings('label')` selects only the siblings that are `<label>` elements, then `.removeClass('checkMark')` removes your `checkMark` `class`.

```
$(element).siblings('label').removeClass('checkMark');
```

**EDIT 2:**

You may want to add a conditional that tests to see if it's on the relevant input element, although I'm sure it certainly won't hurt to let it run on all of the elements.

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/74u7g/6/

```
if ( $(element).parent().is('#confirmPassContainer') ) {
    $(element).siblings('label').removeClass('checkMark');
}
```

Comment: You the man Sparky! That definitely worked. What I do not understand is the "function (element, errorClass)". Element refers to the label? errorClass refers to the label class?

Answer (score 1):

you can fix the problem by using CSS priority.

```
.regForms .error {
    display:block;
    color:#c92a00 !important;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

In your case, when the 2nd password is not the same as the first, you have 2 CSS rules at the same time with 2 color definition. !important allow you to give priority to the error one.

Comment: Thanks, definitely more than one way to skin this cat. Was hoping for a solution within the validate plugin though.